# How to set animation on first element on loading?

Tags: css, angular, systemjs

I am using Angular2 with SystemJs. I am wondering how can I set some animation (like fade-out effect) on the `Loading` label in this [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/pofXHp6yiko61nCpImWV?p=preview). We can see the label before the application loads. Is there a way to add fade out effect when the content of the following changes (index.html):

```
  <body>
    <my-app>loading...</my-app>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS leaves some room for improvement

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',

  template: `
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `,
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
  host: { 
    '[class.loaded]': 'isLoaded',
  },
})
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/',   name: 'Main View',     component: MainViewComponent}
])
export class AppComponent { 
  isLoaded:boolean = false;
  constructor(){}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    setTimeout(() => this.isLoaded = true, 0);
  }
}
```

```
<style>
  my-app {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
  }
  my-app.loaded {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear;
  }
  div.spinner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 150px;
  }

  my-app.loaded + div.spinner {
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility 0s 2s, opacity 2s linear;
    background-color: red;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <my-app></my-app>
  <div class="spinner">loading...</div>
</body>
```

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/GdVhWeaEnrVZRWHkvnPQ?p=preview)

Comment: I'm trying to access your plunker. But it is not getting opened. Is there something wrong in there?

Comment: Happens a lot. It will come back. My answer contains the essential parts anyway.

Comment: yes lately realized that it is down. Thanks though for the information.

Comment: Gunter yes your answer does contain essential parts but still wanted to see it live.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is add a class hidden to the label, and after load app remove the class.

To achieve the fade animation with css add this properties to the label:

```
transition: all 0.5s
opacity: 1
```

And to the class hidden

```
.hidden {
    opacity: 0 !important
}
```

When you remove the hidden class it will animate opacity to default value that is 1 (100%).

If you have JQuery in your app can use $('label').fadeOut(). But nowadays is better use pure CSS

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helped a lot. Kudos to you!!!