# How can I fade out a loader when an Angular Dart application has loaded?

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

My `index.html` file contains the following:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <script defer src="main.dart" type="application/dart"></script>
    <script defer src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="loader-wrapper"></div>
    <my-app></my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to fade out the `loader-wrapper` `div` when `my-app` has loaded.

Initially I considered binding to the `OnInit` method within the `my-app` class, then accessing the DOM outside the `my-app` element to fade out the `loader-wrapper` `div`. This didn't feel like a good solution as I would've thought that code within the `my-app` class should only manipulate DOM within the `my-app` element.

Does the `my-app` element fire any sort of events which I could bind to using a snippet of JavaScript placed in the above `index.html` file?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36234211/how-to-set-animation-on-first-element-on-loading/

Answer (score 1):

I use css to display content if the contents of my-app is empty, and then hide it when the app loads.

```
.loader-wrapper {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .8s ease-in-out;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

my-app:empty + .loader-wrapper {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15%;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Style the loader-wrapper in the my-app empty style however you'd like it to appear while the app is loading, and create an additional styles the same way (for example, so style an h2 tag for your loader you would do this:

```
my-app:empty + . loader-wrapper h2 {
    color: #EEE;
    padding-top: 20px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

Once the app loads, content loads into the my-app div, so it's no longer empty and the .loader-wrapper style fades out.

```
 < my-app ></my-app >

 <div class="loader-wrapper">
      <h2>Loading</h2>
      <span class="loginCopyright">&copy; Your Ace from Outer Space</span>
 </div>
```